# hello, i wan to know how to use PresenceUpdate but its execute every 5 Minutes - Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i want to make so my codes only executed every 5 mins:

```js
     client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
            const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('707085819839512628')

            const rolee = guild.roles.cache.get("707416808835252245")
            if(oldPresence.member.user.bot || newPresence.member.user.bot) return;
            
            let oldState = oldPresence.activities[0]?.state
            let newState = newPresence.activities[0]?.state
            if(oldState === newState) return;
            if(newState.includes("https://discord.gg/indos")) {
                newPresence.member.roles.add(rolee)
            }
        })
        }, 60000);
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO21p.png)

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Just pointing out that your link is not working properly, you can change `[example][2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO21p.png` to `[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO21p.png)` to make it work

Comment: @Toasty i don't get any error i just want to know how to make it only execute every 5 minutes, thanks!

Comment: This is not really possible. `client.on(EVENT)` triggers every time, something happens (hence event). 
If you want to check that every 5 minutes, you would have to loop through every presence every 5 minutes, save that, loop through 5 minutes later, and compare those. 
You could do that using `node-schedule`, but you would have to ditch this event completely.

Answer (score -1):

Good afternoon, what need do you have to execute that code every X seconds? The "`Client.on (Event)`" function captures all the events related to your search at the moment they are executed...

The error for which the role is not granted may be because you do not have a specific Intent enabled, so make sure to activate them and rerun the code by eliminating the function that runs every X seconds.

```js
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
         const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('707085819839512628')

         const rolee = guild.roles.cache.get("707416808835252245")
         if(oldPresence.member.user.bot || newPresence.member.user.bot) return;
            
         let oldState = oldPresence.activities[0]?.state
         let newState = newPresence.activities[0]?.state
         if(oldState === newState) return;
         if(newState.includes("https://discord.gg/url")) {
             newPresence.member.roles.add(rolee)
         }
})
```

Comment: How does this help to execute OP's code every 5 mins? And why did you post the same code as OP?

Comment: Because you don't need yo execute It every 5 minutes

Comment: The code automatically checks your code every time a user changes status